# Android Facebook Version 3.4 - Sort News Feed

Tags: facebook

My Samsung Galaxy S 3 just updated to Android Facebook Version 3.4.

I cannot figure out how to sort News Feed by most recent?

Answer (score 6):

Tap the "hamburger" menu in the upper left. (Looks like three short horizontal lines.) That opens a menu.

[image: hamburger menu]

Next to "News Feed" is a gear icon. Tap that.

[image: Menu]

Your two choices are "Top Stories" and "Most Recent". A checkmark will indicate the current setting. Tap the one you want.

[image: News Feed menu]

Comment: The new version 4.3 doesnt have that icon any more

Comment: @MattBlymire You mean 3.4? And it does for me... What do you see?

Comment: @Matt: Which icon? I double-checked that my version of the Facebook app is 3.4. Perhaps you should add to your question exactly what device and version of the app you have.

Comment: Sorry, 3.4 is correct.  I have Samsung Glaxy S3.

Comment: Along the bottom is now 4 buttons: News Feed, Message, Notifications and Book Marks

Comment: Ummmm...what? That makes no sense. Note, also, that comments are impermanent. You should _[edit] your question_ to include important information or clarifications.

Comment: A screen shot, in this case, would be useful.

Comment: It seems facebook is testing a new UI, but it's not rolled out to all users yet. I've not found any way to sort the news feed yet (i don't have the new UI).